Is there a resource on the differential topology of Banach manifolds?
are there any resources that study the topology of spaces $C^k(M,N)$, where $M$ and $N$ are Banach (maybe even Frechet?) manifolds? I am interested in this since a a sizeable chunk of the book Im currently working through (Geometric theory of dynamical systems) holds without much difference in Banach spaces and manifolds and not just on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and I am interested in looking at if certain stuff still holds or might not, and I need to think about the spaces $C^k (M,N)$ for that. Does anyone know of a reference for questions that go in this direction?
Very thankful for any help!

What exactly do you mean by "certain staff"? For instance, do you mean homotopy-theoretic properties or do you mean general (aka, point-set) topology properties...

More general topological properties.
